# How to upload a file to the server using Synapse

Tags: delphi, upload, ararat-synapse

I'm trying to upload the file using the library [THTTPSendEx](http://arhangelsoft.ru/delphi/advanced-synapse-library-thttpsendex/).

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 HTTP:THTTPSendEx;
 Data:TMultipartFormDataStream;
 sHTML:string; //Recived HTML code from web
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
 HTTP:=THTTPSEndEx.Create;
 Data:=TMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
 try
  Data.AddFile('myFile', OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Data.DataEnd;
  if HTTP.Post('http://kaon.rghost.ru/files',Data,sHTML) then
  begin
  //Connection established
  //Check HTTP response
  if HTTP.IsSuccessfull then  //HTTP returns "200 OK" code.
  begin
    ShowMessage('File successfully posted to the server.');
  end;
  end else
  begin
   ShowMessage('Can not establish a connection to the server...'+#13+'Network is not avaliable or server socket does not exist.');
  end;
 finally
   FreeAndNil(HTTP);
   FreeAndNil(Data);
 end;
end;
end;
```

But nothing prints. Prompt in what a problem?

I'm sorry for the bad translation, I used Google Translater

UPDATE:

Working example for php:

```
$ url = 'http://kaon.rghost.ru/files'; 
$ FILENAME = 'add.png'; 

$ files = array ('file' => '@'. $ FILENAME); 
  
$ useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv: 1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3'; 

   $ ch = curl_init ($ url); 
   curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Content-type: multipart / form-data")); 
   curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
   curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ useragent); 
   curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ files); 
   $ response = curl_exec ($ ch); 

   echo $ response;
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger? What happens when you do?

Comment: No, I have not tried. The code was taken from here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471513/how-to-send-a-file-and-other-post-data-with-synapse

Comment: If you can't be bothered to make any effort in trying to solve your own problem, why should we? Also, the PHP code you posted is entirely superfluous and isn't relevant to a Delphi question.

Comment: What I would try: 1. check (by debugging or logging) the result values of the POST requests: the HTTP error status code, and the body of the response (in the sHTML variable). 2. debug 3. Use a HTTP proxy (for example Fiddler2) to capture and analyze the HTTP request and response

Comment: It's not that I do not try to solve the problem, but the fact that I do not know Delphi and so I bydu very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: May already have a sample? In the Russian segment of the internet I have not found solutions

Answer (score 0):

For file posting, ANY web-site requires cookies and/or post params and/or valid input field name for file. That's minimum what need to post the file to the server.

You just copy example, paste yours url and load file to stream. Nope this didn't works that.

I don't see anything of required by rghost.ru for file posting in your code.

Comment: No, cookies are not needed here, my php script to upload a file without problems:Please look at the code I posted above kotryj

Comment: I say it again: You didn't explore web-site before coding for it. Input field with file is named "choose"

Comment: I researched it, and wrote a script running upload php. Need to send only two values: file (name of the field - "file") and token (field name - "authenticity_token"). The second parameter is optional, and the upload is successful without it.

Comment: Yes, he has successfully loaded files